# The latest time for davening Shacharit

Tags: tefilla, zemanim

I have heard many opinions regarding when one can stop saying [Shacharit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shacharit). I heard some people say chatzot, and some say the 4th hour. I heard some rumors that Sephardim only goes up until the 4th hour. I also heard that the brachot of kriat shema only goes up to the 4th hour. What is the explanation?

I would ideally like the Sephardic opinion.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Yehoshua and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper time for shacharit is until the 4th hour. If one missed the time they can still daven until midday. See [Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 89](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.89.1?lang=bi):

> And its time continues until the end of four hours which is a third of
> the daytime.  And if one erred or transgressed and prayed after the
> fourth hour until noon, even though one does not have the [same]
> reward as praying at its [proper] time, in any case there is still a
> reward of prayer. <sub>Rem"a:  And after noon it is forbidden to pray
> the Tefillah of the morning (Beit Yosef in the name of  the Rashba
> [Rabbi Shlomo ben Adret], Chapter: "Morning Prayer").</sub>

Comment: Just to add -- latest time for Shema is 1 "relative" hour earlier.  Anyhow. This is discussed in the Gemara and not subject to Sefardi/Ashkenazi debates. (There are some Hassidim who feel "better between 4th and noon with more concentration, than earlier with poor concentration", but they're still agreeing that this is the timetable with which we start.)

Comment: What about brachot of keriat shema? When is the latest time for them?

Comment: @JoelK That's less cut and dry. S"A says 4 hours is the cutoff, but some are lenient until midday.

Comment: thanks shmosel for the answer when i said sephardic opinion, i really for the brachot of kriat shema i didn't make it that clear so its kinda my fault but thank u

Comment: @shmosel Others are lenient all day

Comment: @DoubleAA source for that?

Comment: @yehoshuanisanov It’s probably the simplest way to read Rambam Hilchot KS 1:13